# Android - can't combine views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one Activity in which I try to show some simple messages, and then a list of items. So as I understand, I need two views: one for the simple layout, and one for the list of items which will be handled by the adapter.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<SolutionTopic> adapter;        

ArrayList<SolutionTopic> problems = new ArrayList <SolutionTopic>( );
```

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
// Load your layout
setContentView(R.layout.solution);

SolutionTopic s = new SolutionTopic ();
s.setSolutionTopicName( "Hello" );

problems.add(s);        

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SolutionTopic>(this, R.layout.solution_topic_list, 
        R.id.label,  problems);

TextView solution_title  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution_title);        
TextView solution_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution_description);

setListAdapter (adapter);
```

}

and here is the solution.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/solution_title"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label1"
    />  

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/solution_description"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label2"
    />  

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the solution_topic_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

What I am not sure is how to get these two to render together. Ideally what I want to do is display the TextView messages first, and then the list of items.

Any idea how I can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your Activity a subclass of ListActivity?  What do you see currently when you start your Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't remove the ListView from solution.xml, in that ListView your SolutionTopics will be displayed.

To get the big picture, your interface would have three Views:

-TextView: @+id/solution_title

-TextView: @+id/solution_description

-ListView: @android:id/list

The ListView contains an undefined number of entries of solution_topic_list.xml.

PD: The third parameter of ArrayAdapter (R.id.label) should be the id of the TextView in solution_topic_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

You also should implement toString method in your SolutionTopic class, to get the desired String.

Comment: I am kind of confused how to make the two xml files work together and how to call them correctly in the code. Could you please explain to me how that is supposed to all work together?  Thanks!

Comment: This article explains well everything related with ListViews: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html Read it carefully. If then you don't understand something, ask here :)

Comment: Great!!!!! Maybe you could mark your other question as solved, and give me the bounty :D